# Is there a way to remove the white spacing at the end of the animation?

Tags: html, css

I know its because of the `translate:300px` but without it the animation makes a sudden jump to first image which doesn't look very nice. I tried everything any help would be appreciated.

```css
.container {
        outline: 1px solid red;
        width: 250px;
        overflow: hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;
       
    }

    .image-wrapper {
        translate: 300px;
        animation: scroll 3s linear infinite ;
    }
    .image-wrapper > img {
        width:250px
    }

    @keyframes scroll {
        100% {
            translate: -750px;
        }

    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="image-wrapper">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1662590653876-49029aa90353?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxMHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60"
                alt="">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1662556224812-06ee64dec478?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHw4fHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60"
                alt="">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1662421744749-b8ce69a99c10?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxNXx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60"
                alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You'd need javascript. [This](https://codepen.io/zuraizm/pen/DwZaqx) looks nice

Comment: One could also animate each image individually instead of the whole container. With `animation-delay` you can start them at the correct time, then when it leaves the view, immediately set it back to right side. Needs good timings but it's possible without JS

Answer (score 0):

Reduce the translation at the end by little bit.

```
@keyframes scroll {
    100% {
        translate: -550px;
    }

}
```

This will solve your issue. But if your target is to prepare a carousel, use **bootstrap carousel** or other one like **owl carousel** which has much inbuilt functionalities.